# Why is "@android:id/tabs" not being able to be found?

Tags: android, tabs

I am following a tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=irDdBxamuZs 
I'm trying to implement these tabs for the first time. When I drag a tab host over, it just gives me this red straight away in the XML saying it can't find them:

[image]

In the sample project:[image]

Can anyone shine some light on why this could be? Sorry if it's a noobie question, it's just i'm really stuck and been trying for hours following loads of bad / deprecated tutorials

Comment: @KonradKrakowiak : android default id 's doesn't need a + sign! that means adding new id to R file.

Comment: Could you help me Arash?

Comment: it should be something about your xml namespaces , let me check again your image.

Comment: All i'm doing is starting a new Blank Activity, dragging over a tab host, and this happens, could you perhaps try replicate?

Comment: Infact, I just did it and it seems to work.. Must be something i'm changing, i'll get back to you.. EDIT: Oh wait, no I built it, then after the build had happened and I went back to the XML, it all came up in red again

Comment: It seems to be coming up in red, but is able to build

Comment: Hi Arash, i've just started ignoring the fact they're red. Seems to be working now. Still, very odd...

Comment: unfortunately i dont work with Android Studio yet so dont know why they are red . as long as its working so its not that important ;)

Comment: yeah, i used to use eclipse too but I went on their website and they seem to have said that it's now their core IDE